# Function/library to create a temporary file/directory in Node.js

Tags: gratis, library, file-management, node.js

I want to create a temporary file (or directory), similarly to what the Linux [mkstemp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp) command does.

With what software can I do that in [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)?

Requirements:

- Free
- Open source
- Secure randome name, to avoid any [symlink race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink_race)
- Fast
- Reasonably small

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/raszi/node-tmp

> A simple temporary file and directory creator for node.js.

- Does just that
- Free
- Open source: MIT License
- Updated 3 months ago
- Has not reached 1.0

Example usage:

```
var tmp = require('tmp');

var tmpobj = tmp.dirSync();
console.log("Dir: ", tmpobj.name);

// Manual cleanup
tmpobj.removeCallback();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Node.js 5.10.1](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.10.1/CHANGELOG.md#2016-03-31-version-5100-stable-evanlucas) or later, there is a native function:

```
fs.mkdtemp()
```

- Does not seem to have any documentation yet
- Works only for folders

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bruce/node-temp

> Temporary files, directories, and streams for Node.js.

- Does streams too
- Automatically track and cleanup files at exit
- Free
- Open source: MIT License
- Updated a year ago
- Has not reached 1.0

Example usage:

```
var temp = require('temp'),
    fs   = require('fs'),
    util  = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Automatically track and cleanup files at exit
temp.track();

// Fake data
var myData = "foo\nbar\nfoo\nbaz";

// Process the data (note: error handling omitted)
temp.open('myprefix', function(err, info) {
  if (!err) {
    fs.write(info.fd, myData);
    fs.close(info.fd, function(err) {
      exec("grep foo '" + info.path + "' | wc -l", function(err, stdout) {
        util.puts(stdout.trim());
      });
    });
  }
});
```